# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session' AT LOGIN

Tags: python, django, iis

I'm trying to teach myself python\Django. This was built in Visual Studio with the Django starter site so all the settings.py etc where prebuilt and just added upon.

When I attempt to login to the site from the IIS Server I get:

> AttributeError at /login/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute
>   'session'

although when I attempt to run it on my local machine from `python manage.py runserver` it runs just fine.

**django.VERSION (2, 0, 0, 'final', 0)**


**settings.py:**

```
import os
import posixpath

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'c94808af-46cc-47da-b465-4e66803a8324'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AllFlexHub.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AllFlexHub.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]




LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

**views.py:**

```
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response, get_object_or_404
    from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from datetime import datetime
    from app.models import *
    from app.forms import *

    def home(request):
        """Renders the home page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/index.html',
            {
                'title':'Home Page',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def Register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = RegisterUser(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            form = RegisterUser()

        return render(request, 'app\Register.html', {'form': form})


    def contact(request):
        """Renders the contact page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/contact.html',
            {
                'title':'Contacts',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def about(request):
        """Renders the about page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/about.html',
            {
                'title':'About',
                'message':'All Flex IT Tools.',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def problemreports(request):
        """Renders the home page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/problemreport.html',
            {
                'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Status__startswith='Act'),
                'title':'Problem Reports',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def myPRs(request):
        """Renders the home page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/problemreport.html',
            {
                'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(User=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)),
                'title':'Problem Reports',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def Closed(request):
        """Renders the home page."""
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
            request,
            'app/problemreport.html',
            {
                'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Status__startswith='Close'),
                'title':'Problem Reports',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        )

    def SearchPRs(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            Sval = request.POST['SearchField']
            frm = request.POST['SearchOption']
            form = Search()
            if frm == "Ticket_Number":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Ticket_Number__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "User":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(User__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "Title":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Title__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "Bldg":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Bldg__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "Description":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Description__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "Computer":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Computer__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            elif frm == "Status":
                return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', { 'reports': PRTickets.objects.filter(Status__icontains = Sval), 'form': form})
            form = Search()
        else:
            form = Search()
            return render(request, 'app\SearchPRs.html', {'form': form})

    def PRNewItem(request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            form = PRticektform(initial={'User': User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)})
            return render(
                request,
                'app/NewItem.html',
                {
                'form':form ,
                'now':datetime.now(),
                'title': 'SEARCH',
                }
            )
            return render(request, 'app/NewItem.html', )
        elif request.method == "POST":
            form = PRticektform(request.POST)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/problemreports')

    def EditPR(request, name):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            val = PRTickets.objects.get(Ticket_Number=name)
            val.User = request.POST['User']
            val.Title = request.POST['Title']
            val.Bldg = request.POST['Bldg']
            val.Computer = request.POST['Computer']
            val.Description = request.POST['Description']
            val.Status = request.POST['Status']
            val.save()
            cmmts = Comments(Comment=request.POST['Comment'], User=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username), Related_PR=val)
            cmmts.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/problemreports')
        else:
            PRinfo = PRTickets.objects.get(Ticket_Number=name)
            form = EditPRs(
                initial={
                'User': PRinfo.User,
                'Title': PRinfo.Title,
                'Bldg': PRinfo.Bldg,
                'Computer': PRinfo.Computer,
                'Description': PRinfo.Description,
                'Status': PRinfo.Status,
                }
                )

        return render(request, 'app/EditPR.html',
            {'form': form,
            'PRNumber': name,
            'title': name,
            'Fields': PRTickets.objects.get(Ticket_Number=name),
            'Comms': Comments.objects.filter(Related_PR=name),
            }
        )
```

**urls.py:**

    `"""
    Definition of urls for ITWebsite.
    """`

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url
import django.contrib.auth.views

import app.forms
import app.views

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
# from django.conf.urls import include
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^Register', app.views.Register, name='Register'),
    url(r'^problemreports$', app.views.problemreports, name='problemreports'),
    url(r'^problemreports/NewItem', app.views.PRNewItem, name='PRNewItem'),
    url(r'^problemreports/MyProblemReports', app.views.myPRs, name='myPRs'),
    url(r'^problemreports/Closed', app.views.Closed, name='Closed'),
    url(r'^problemreports/SearchPRs', app.views.SearchPRs, name='SearchPRs'),
    url(r'^problemreports/(\d{1,10})', app.views.EditPR, name='EditPR'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.login,
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Log in',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
        {
            'next_page': '/',
        },
        name='logout'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots; that just makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Post your `urls.py` and `views.py` modules.

Comment: updated with urls.py and views.py and added them as "code"

Comment: Importing django and running .VERSION  it shows
(2, 0, 0, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting is [deprecated in Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#id3), and [removed in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0).

You should define [`MIDDLEWARE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) in your settings instead.

`SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` was removed in Django 2.0, so you should remove that from the list.

Comment: I removed  "_CLASSES" and stopped website/saved/restarted website in iis and it still has the same error.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in  your question, and say which version of Django you are using.

Comment: It might not be enough to simply rename the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting to `MIDDLEWARE` -- it might have a different format, different ordering, etc.

Comment: Actually I started to get a 500 error on page when I do just MIDDLEWARE

Comment: You still have `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in your list of `MIDDLEWARE`. It was removed in Django 2.0. The [docs I linked to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) show the default `MIDDLEWARE` for a new project.

Comment: after commenting out the old middle ware and coping and pasting the middleware from the link you sent me it started working.
thank you