# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session' and 'user'

Tags: python, django

My project middle setting is failing:

[image]

I have checked request as shown above and it doesn't contain user and session. I don't know where is the problem.

Can you give me some suggestions?

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: the detail of request object can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QTA8.png

Comment: Replace `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` with `MIDDLEWARE`. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756738/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-session-at-login

Comment: Thank  you very much ,because i also use xadmin ,xadmin also used MIDDLE_CLASSESS，so i must modify this module also ，after that ,it's work well